# * Error: Data directory ... must not be owned by root

Tags: postgresql, google-colaboratory

I follow these steps to change postgres data directory to `/content` in google colab:

```
from pathlib import Path 

!sudo apt-get install postgresql

current_dir = '/var/lib/postgresql'
new_dir = '/content'

!sudo service postgresql stop

if not (Path(new_dir) / 'postgres').exists():
    !rsync -av $current_dir $new_dir

conf_path = '/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf'
with open(conf_path) as f:
    conf = f.read().replace(current_dir, (Path(new_dir) / 'postgresql').as_posix())
with open(conf_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(conf)
```

then:

```
!sudo service postgresql restart

* Restarting PostgreSQL 14 database server
   ...done.
```

However, if `new_dir` is changed from `/content` to `/content/drive/MyDrive`, with all steps repeated, it stops working:

```
from google.colab import drive
from pathlib import Path

drive.mount('/content/drive')
new_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive'
# repeat all above
# ...

!sudo service postgresql restart

* Restarting PostgreSQL 14 database server
* Error: Data directory /content/drive/MyDrive/postgresql/14/main must not be owned by root
...fail!
```

I tried this and I get the same result:

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres $new_dir
```